# How to continue while loop after exception raised in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql

How would I continue the while loop after an exception has been raised in the code below?

```
DECLARE    
  v_blob_data       BLOB;    
  v_blob_len        NUMBER;    
  v_position        NUMBER;    
  v_raw_chunk       RAW(10000);    
  v_char      CHAR(1);    
  c_chunk_len   number       := 1;    
  v_line        VARCHAR2 (32767)        := NULL;    
  v_data_array      wwv_flow_global.vc_arr2;    
  v_rows number;    
  v_sr_no number := 1;  
  v_first_line_done boolean := false;  
  v_error_cd number :=0;  
  v_quote_pos1 NUMBER;  
  v_quote_pos2 NUMBER;  
  v_enclosed_str VARCHAR(200);
  v_errmsg VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  delete from TEMP_MM_UPDATE where username = :P1_USER_ID;

  -- Read data from wwv_flow_files</span>    
  select    
    blob_content    
    into v_blob_data    
    from wwv_flow_files    
    where name = :P2_FILE_UPLOAD; 

  v_blob_len := dbms_lob.getlength(v_blob_data);    
  v_position := 1; 

  -- Read and convert binary to char</span>  
  WHILE ( v_position <= v_blob_len )    
  LOOP 
    begin  
        v_raw_chunk := dbms_lob.substr(v_blob_data,c_chunk_len,v_position);    
        v_char :=  chr(hex_to_decimal(rawtohex(v_raw_chunk)));    
        v_line := v_line || v_char;    
        v_position := v_position + c_chunk_len;

      -- When a whole line is retrieved </span>   
      IF v_char = CHR(10) THEN
        LOOP  
          --Make sure there's something to replace  
          IF INSTR(v_line, '"', 1, 1) = 0 THEN  
            EXIT; -- If nothing to replace, exit loop and don't try  
          END IF;  
          --Find the position of the first and second quotes in the line of text  
          v_quote_pos1 := INSTR(v_line, '"', 1, 1);  
          v_quote_pos2 := INSTR(v_line, '"', 1, 2);  
          --Extract the inner string  
          v_enclosed_str := SUBSTR(v_line, v_quote_pos1 + 1, v_quote_pos2 - v_quote_pos1 - 1);  
          --perform the replacement  
          v_line := SUBSTR(v_line, 0, v_quote_pos1 - 1) || REPLACE(v_enclosed_str, ',', '<') || SUBSTR(v_line, v_quote_pos2 + 1);  
        END LOOP; 

        -- Convert comma to : to use wwv_flow_utilities </span>  
        v_line := REPLACE (v_line, ',', ':');  
        v_line := REPLACE (v_line, '<', ',');  
        v_line := REPLACE (trim(v_line), '-', NULL);  
        --v_line := REPLACE (trim(v_line), '"', NULL);  
        -- Convert each column separated by : into array of data </span>    
        v_data_array := wwv_flow_utilities.string_to_table (v_line);  
        --Check to see if the row of column headers has already been parsed through  
        IF(v_first_line_done != true)THEN   
          v_first_line_done := true;  
          --Check column order in spreadsheet  
          IF(v_data_array(1)    LIKE '%Username%' AND
              v_data_array(2)  LIKE '%NDN%' AND
              v_data_array(3)  LIKE '%PCFN%') THEN   
            v_error_cd := 0;  
            v_line := NULL;  
          ELSE  
            v_error_cd := 1;  
          END IF;  
        --If first line is done and the column order is correct then  
        ELSIF(v_first_line_done = true AND v_error_cd = 0) THEN   
          -- Insert data into target table </span>    
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into TEMP_MM_UPDATE   
          (USERNAME,
           RPT_FLAG,
           PCFN)
          values (:1,:2,:3)'   
           USING   
            v_data_array(1),   
            v_data_array(2),   
            v_data_array(3);    
           -- Clear out    
            v_line := NULL; v_sr_no := v_sr_no + 1; 
        END IF;  
      END IF;
    exception
      WHEN OTHERS then
        v_errmsg := SQLERRM;
        insert into temp_mm_update (username,error_desc)
        values (:P1_USER_ID, v_errmsg);
  END;
  END LOOP;

  DELETE FROM WWV_FLOW_FILES where name = :P2_FILE_UPLOAD;
  DELETE FROM TEMP_MM_UPDATE WHERE USERNAME IS NULL AND PCFN IS NULL;  
  IF(v_error_cd = 1) THEN  
    INSERT INTO temp_mm_update (USERNAME, ERROR_DESC)  
    VALUES (:P1_USER_ID, 'Error. Please check column order in spreadsheet.');  
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    insert into temp_mm_update (username,error_desc)
    values (:P1_USER_ID, 'No Data Found.');
  WHEN OTHERS then
    v_errmsg := SQLERRM;
    insert into temp_mm_update (username,error_desc)
    values (:P1_USER_ID, v_errmsg);
END;
```

When I put the exception inside the loop like above, the procedure never seems to finish and I end up getting a "NOWAIT" error when I try to delete the table or anything like that.

The code works fine if I take out the "BEGIN" right after the loop and also take out the exception inside the loop, but I want to be able to specify what is wrong with every record instead  of processing correct records and then stopping after it comes to a record that has, for example, 9 values in a column that only accepts 6.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks,

Steven

EDITS: 
I changed the line: 
    ELSIF(v_first_line_done = true AND v_error_cd = 0) 
to
     ELSIF(v_first_line_done = true AND v_error_cd = 0 AND (v_data_array(1) is not null OR v_data_array(1) not like '%-%'))
and the procedure finishes, but when it comes to a record that raises and exception, all of the following records have the same exception.

Sample of my CSV File:
Username    NDN PCFN
DOOL0008    X   808461
DOOL0008    X   886332
DOOL0008    X   887223
DOOL0008    X   887992
DOOL0008    X   904959
DOOL0008    X   904959
DOOL0008    X   904968
DOOL0008    X   904968

So for example if the column MM (which had a datatype of VARCHAR2(1)) has a value of "XX" on the third record, and exception will be raised that the value is too large, and then for records 4-8 the same exception will be raised.

Comment: It looks to me like there's an `END;` statement missing before the last `END LOOP;`.

Comment: @BobJarvis sorry I forgot to add that in on this code. In the code I actually used, the END; was in there before the END LOOP;

Comment: Post here some sample content of the blob_content, please, so it would be possible to debug the code.

Comment: I tried your code with some "reverse engineered" data and it works fine. If your procedure never finishes, then it probably means that your procedure ends up stuck in an endless loop. A sample of your `blob_content` would really help.

Comment: @nop77svk I edited my post with some of my CSV file data. Hope that is the blob_content you were refering to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By playing around with my code I figured out what was wrong. 
I needed to add in the following line into my exception block of code:

```
v_line := NULL; v_sr_no := v_sr_no + 1;
```

Final code:

```
  DECLARE    
  v_blob_data       BLOB;    
  v_blob_len        NUMBER;    
  v_position        NUMBER;    
  v_raw_chunk       RAW(10000);    
  v_char      CHAR(1);    
  c_chunk_len   number       := 1;    
  v_line        VARCHAR2 (32767)        := NULL;    
  v_data_array      wwv_flow_global.vc_arr2;    
  v_rows number;    
  v_sr_no number := 1;  
  v_first_line_done boolean := false;  
  v_error_cd number :=0;  
  v_quote_pos1 NUMBER;  
  v_quote_pos2 NUMBER;  
  v_enclosed_str VARCHAR(200);
  v_errmsg VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  delete from TEMP_MM_UPDATE where username = :P1_USER_ID;

  -- Read data from wwv_flow_files</span>    
  select    
    blob_content    
    into v_blob_data    
    from wwv_flow_files    
    where name = :P2_FILE_UPLOAD; 

  v_blob_len := dbms_lob.getlength(v_blob_data);    
  v_position := 1; 

  -- Read and convert binary to char</span>  
  WHILE ( v_position <= v_blob_len )    
  LOOP 
    begin  
        v_raw_chunk := dbms_lob.substr(v_blob_data,c_chunk_len,v_position);    
        v_char :=  chr(hex_to_decimal(rawtohex(v_raw_chunk)));    
        v_line := v_line || v_char;    
        v_position := v_position + c_chunk_len;

      -- When a whole line is retrieved </span>   
      IF v_char = CHR(10) THEN
        LOOP  
          --Make sure there's something to replace  
          IF INSTR(v_line, '"', 1, 1) = 0 THEN  
            EXIT; -- If nothing to replace, exit loop and don't try  
          END IF;  
          --Find the position of the first and second quotes in the line of text  
          v_quote_pos1 := INSTR(v_line, '"', 1, 1);  
          v_quote_pos2 := INSTR(v_line, '"', 1, 2);  
          --Extract the inner string  
          v_enclosed_str := SUBSTR(v_line, v_quote_pos1 + 1, v_quote_pos2 - v_quote_pos1 - 1);  
          --perform the replacement  
          v_line := SUBSTR(v_line, 0, v_quote_pos1 - 1) || REPLACE(v_enclosed_str, ',', '<') || SUBSTR(v_line, v_quote_pos2 + 1);  
        END LOOP; 

        -- Convert comma to : to use wwv_flow_utilities </span>  
        v_line := REPLACE (v_line, ',', ':');  
        v_line := REPLACE (v_line, '<', ',');  
        v_line := REPLACE (trim(v_line), '-', NULL);  
        --v_line := REPLACE (trim(v_line), '"', NULL);  
        -- Convert each column separated by : into array of data </span>    
        v_data_array := wwv_flow_utilities.string_to_table (v_line);  
        --Check to see if the row of column headers has already been parsed through  
        IF(v_first_line_done != true)THEN   
          v_first_line_done := true;  
          --Check column order in spreadsheet  
          IF(v_data_array(1)    LIKE '%Username%' AND
              v_data_array(2)  LIKE '%NDN%' AND
              v_data_array(3)  LIKE '%PCFN%') THEN   
            v_error_cd := 0;  
            v_line := NULL;  
          ELSE  
            v_error_cd := 1;  
          END IF;  
        --If first line is done and the column order is correct then  
        ELSIF(v_first_line_done = true AND v_error_cd = 0) THEN   
          -- Insert data into target table </span>    
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into TEMP_MM_UPDATE   
          (USERNAME,
           RPT_FLAG,
           PCFN)
          values (:1,:2,:3)'   
           USING   
            v_data_array(1),   
            v_data_array(2),   
            v_data_array(3);    
           -- Clear out    
            v_line := NULL; v_sr_no := v_sr_no + 1; 
        END IF;  
      END IF;
    exception
      WHEN OTHERS then
        v_errmsg := SQLERRM;
        insert into temp_mm_update (username,error_desc)
        values (:P1_USER_ID, v_errmsg);
v_line := NULL; v_sr_no := v_sr_no + 1; 
  END;
  END LOOP;

  DELETE FROM WWV_FLOW_FILES where name = :P2_FILE_UPLOAD;
  DELETE FROM TEMP_MM_UPDATE WHERE USERNAME IS NULL AND PCFN IS NULL;  
  IF(v_error_cd = 1) THEN  
    INSERT INTO temp_mm_update (USERNAME, ERROR_DESC)  
    VALUES (:P1_USER_ID, 'Error. Please check column order in spreadsheet.');  
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    insert into temp_mm_update (username,error_desc)
    values (:P1_USER_ID, 'No Data Found.');
  WHEN OTHERS then
    v_errmsg := SQLERRM;
    insert into temp_mm_update (username,error_desc)
    values (:P1_USER_ID, v_errmsg);
END;
```